# How to retrieve Appearance > Menus in Wordpress 2.9?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In Wordpress 2.9, how can you restore 'Menus' to the Appearance section of the dashboard? I've been told it requires adding code to functions.php, since uploading a new theme, but almost all of the code examples I find are for 3.0 - 3.5 versions of Wordpress. I'm editing someone else's existing website. My first recommendation was to update, but they wish to stay with the older version.

Comment: You're still running 2.9? That's a serious security risk, don't do it, update now and chose a different theme if it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Appreciate the concern, and I don't disagree. Believe me. In the end, we upgraded and modified the existing theme to work; though, not 100% perfectly. In short, the theme was too custom and specific to just replace with an alternative. If it broke upon update, the only viable course of action was to refurb the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't be "restoring" it, you'd be adding it.  IIRC the custom menu features (Appearance -> Menus) was added in Wordpress 3.0 and didn't exist in 2.9.  It might be possible to hack it in, but it could be a lot of work since 3.0 was a very significant update to Wordpress core.

You will probably either need to upgrade to 3.0 (or 3.5.1... which is the smart option since running an ancient version of Wordpress like 2.9 is a huge security risk) or write some kind of custom plugin that will mimic the custom menus functionality in 3.0.  If you want to try to hack the feature in using the 3.0 code you'll need to dig pretty deep into core WP code to do so and it would probably take more work than either of the other two options.

Adding code to `functions.php` like you are describing is for 3.0+ versions of WP where you enable the custom menus feature with a single line of code - this won't work in 2.9 since the functionality doesn't exist in core WP for that version.  Your client needs to pick between upgrading or paying you to write this feature yourself - they can't expect you to cherry-pick random features from subsequent major WP releases and just "add" them in an older version of WP since they all depend on the updated core files to work at all.

Comment: Much appreciate the reply. For now, I'll just use exclude within `wp_list_pages()`. Unfortunately, I don't think we can remake the whole theme if upgrading to 3.0+ is needed. If you can provide any tips or resources that could help significantly speed up theme conversion, I'd love to know of some.